# UnmanagedType.ByValArray byte[] in Struct won't Compile in x64

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, struct, resharper, c#-6.0

Current struct:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 16, Pack = 8)]
    private struct SubStruct
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 8)]
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public byte[] Array;
        [FieldOffset(8)] public MockEnum MockEnum;
    }
```

This struct simply existing in my Unit Test project prevents resharper from running it under x64 settings. I just get the "Inconclusive, Test wasn't run" error.

Compiling in x86 works fine, and if I comment out the byte array and its two attributes, I can compile in x64 no problem.

So for some reason something about `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 8)]` isn't getting along with x64?

Running it in VS2015, C#6.0, .Net 4.6.2, Resharper 2017.1.3

Update: 
Works fine on this setup: VS2017, C#7.0, .net 4.5.2, Resharper 2017.1.3

Must be a .net problem or visual studio 2015 problem?

Comment: Just existing?  It's not being used anywhere?  Is your unit testing project testing unmanaged code?

Comment: It's just a little odd because the way the structure is set up is like for direct memory access, but 'fixed' isn't being used in front of the array, which it probably should be in that case, but that's kind of hardcore for unit-testing code

Comment: Even using LayoutKind.Sequential I still get the same issue, LayoutKind doesn't seem to matter.

It crashes even if I am not using the struct, correct. I commented out the part of my unit test that uses the struct and it still won't run, even though the unit test isn't even handling the struct. Simply existing in the Namespace is enough to make the unit test stop working it looks like.

Comment: I tried it out in VS2017 at home and it runs no problem on both x64 and x86 so it must be a .net or resharper problem.

VS2017, C# 7.0, .net 4.5.2, x64, Resharper 2017.1.3